# iOS 9 eliminated MKDirectionsRequest property "source". How to handle?

Tags: swift, ios9

Prior to iOS9, my code to request map directions looked like that below. Except the second line generates an error since the source property has been removed. How to handle?

```
let request = MKDirectionsRequest()
request.setSource(MKMapItem.mapItemForCurrentLocation())
```

Comment: How about `request.source = MKMapItem.mapItemForCurrentLocation()` ?

Comment: Oh my! request.source = MKMapItem.mapItemForCurrentLocation() works! Not sure why setSource() stopped working yet. Thanks

Comment: It is not Xcode but rather Swift updated to version 2.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<kbd>Command</kbd>-clicking on `MKDirectionsRequest` reveals the following:

**In Xcode 6.4 (Swift 1.2):**

```
@availability(iOS, introduced=6.0)
class MKDirectionsRequest : NSObject {

    @availability(iOS, introduced=6.0)
    func source() -> MKMapItem!
    @availability(iOS, introduced=7.0)
    func setSource(source: MKMapItem!)

    @availability(iOS, introduced=6.0)
    func destination() -> MKMapItem!
    @availability(iOS, introduced=7.0)
    func setDestination(destination: MKMapItem!)
}
```

**In Xcode 7 (Swift 2.0):**

```
@available(iOS 6.0, *)
public class MKDirectionsRequest : NSObject {

    public var source: MKMapItem?

    public var destination: MKMapItem?
}
```

So apparently `setSource` is gone, and the proper way to set the value is:

```
request.source = MKMapItem.mapItemForCurrentLocation()
```